# Call an object's superclass methods outside the hierarchy

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, multiplayer

I'm working on a game , and it's the first time i added multiplayer (with kryonet) , it was designed as a singleplayer initialli , then I added multiplayer .I thought of a sort of elegant way to make the same code work both ways. The code works , except an infinite loop that came with my solution .

In my gameplay class I instantiate the foo variable as Foo when the game is singleplayer and as SubFoo when multyplayer , as in the example bellow .Basically SubFoo overrides Foo's methods that are responsible with world changing events ,makes the needed multiplayer calls and then "continues" the method .

**The problem** is that when the client receives the packet from the server it has to call foo in a way so that it skips it's overridden methods so it doesn't sent the changes back to the server and so on .

I tried adding a root variable in the Foo class , hoping that if i call that , it will call the methods of its class , but to no success . I could also make it work if foo calls a method like `foo.fooCaller().method();` .

I should mention that my server is a host .So for 5 players, 4 are clients and one is a host . If there is a better way of doing this ,like a pattern ,I would be glad to hear it .

An example where Foo and SubFoo are the simplified versions of my World and WorldNetwork .

```
public class Foo { // as the main , singleplayer world

    public Foo root;

    public Foo() {
        root = Foo.this;
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println( "This is foo" );
    }

}

// as the extension of the main world that manages the server/client calls
public class SubFoo extends Foo { 

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println( "this is super foo" );
        super.method();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new SubFoo();
    foo.root.method(); // make this skip the SubFoo method
    foo.method(); // this should execut normally 
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `// make this skip the SuperFoo` method meant `// make this skip the SubFoo method`?

Comment: Anyway this seems like a bad pattern, since it breaks the substitution principle (you cannot use an instance of `SubFoo` like an instance of `Foo`, even if they are in an `is an` relationship). Maybe (from the very high level description of the problem) should delegate the communication details to another different class and subclasses.

Comment: The best way to go about it is: you make a superclass and make for singleplayer a subclass and for multiplayer a subclass. I would even let the superclass be abstract.

Comment: fixed that comment , the thing with the way I did it, allowed me to not modify any other place that a World method was called .As i said the game was made as a singleplayer so the architecture wasn't designed with muliplayer in mind . If I could get pointed to a pattern or tutorial that's clear enough (for a networking noob like me) I could re-factor the game  ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to call the method of the `Foo` class, you should not instantiate a `SubFoo` object. You should instantiate a `Foo` object. If on the other hand you need the specific function on `SubFoo` objects, you should inherit the specific function without overriding it.

At the end, you have to decide what the functionality of the `SubFoo` class would be on the `method` call. This functionality cannot change with the context, as the compiler cannot guess which functionality you want to execute.

You could do it using [polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) based on the function arguments. For example:

```
class SubFoo{

    //Inherit the method functionality from Foo
    ...


    //Define new method with another signature to seperate its call
    void method (Object arg);

}
```

In the end, the question is what you want the method to do.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without method alterations , because I could simply add a boolean argument on all Foo methods and if the argument is true and foo is in a multiplayer game it should do a sending info action . That way I wouldn't even have to make SubFoo and Foo's methods would have made pointless checks when in singleplayer .